# Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, 505 MB) doesn't work

Tags: qt, qt5

I have downloaded four Qt 5.1.0 packages:

Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL, 666 MB)

Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, 505 MB)

Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 525 MB)

Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, OpenGL, 522 MB)

After installed all these four packages, I created a very simple
QT project by using **Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, 505 MB)**

The project is a Qt gui application with a ui form. I created it just follow the 
Qt Creator's template without typing any word. After that I built this project 
and run, everything is OK.

Then I added a new C++ class to the project. The added C++ class's base class is QWidget.
This time, I still did not type any word in the .cpp and .h file. So the added class 
only was created by Qt Creator. After that I built this project again, and run, 
everything is still OK.

Now I began to add my code. 
I added one line in the mainwindow.h:

```
#include "myclass.h"
```

Then I added another line in the mainwindow.cpp:

```
pMyClass = new CMyClass(this);
```

After that I built this project again, this time two errors happened.

```
error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol public: __thiscall CMyClass::CMyClass(class QWidget *)" (??0CMyClass@@QAE@PAVQWidget@@@Z)

error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I built the same project by using another three Qt versions:

Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL, 666 MB)

Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 525 MB)

Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, OpenGL, 522 MB)

Build and run were all successful. Everything is OK.

Because my project can be built and run successfully by using

Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 32-bit (MinGW 4.8, OpenGL, 666 MB)

Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, 525 MB)

Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2012, OpenGL, 522 MB)

I am pretty sure there is nothing wrong in my project.

Only using **Qt 5.1.0 for Windows 32-bit (VS 2010, 505 MB)** errors happen.

I was confused by the results. I checked the build directories and I found **VS 2010
did not compile mycalss.cpp!** All other three build directories have the .obj files 
or .o files of myclass. So when link, errors happened.

My System is Windows7 64bit Ultimate. Does anyone know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you add new files (class) to project manually call "Run qmake" through context menu your project. This action create new "Make files" which now include new added files. All this must be perform automatically when changes in *.pro file occur. 
 Through which reason does not work automatically in this version Qt I don't know (((.

Comment: I add the files of the new class by using QT creator template, not added manually. I just wonder, why other three Qt build it successfully, and vs2010 doesn't work?

Comment: It doesn't matter how do you add new files: using QT creator templates or by hand. They must detect changes in *.pro file. I have been working with Qt for a 2 years and in my experience only MinGW version regenerates makefiles automatically. For other versions i have to do this manually.

Comment: Thanks DeaWarlock, you remind me something useful. I have done some tests again and I believe you get the point. Can you tell me how to regenerate makefiles manually when using Qt msvc2010? I have never done this manually before, sorry.

Comment: Thanks DeadWarlock, you remind me something useful. I have done some tests again and I believe you get the point. This time, I first Run qmake, than build the project successfully. Thanks again DeadWarlock, you advice is nice.

Comment: Sorry DeadWarlock, I fogot it. Thank u.